Redefine commands, changing a catcode
Background
I'm the author of the altsubsup package, which set to 12 (other) the catcode of the circumflex ^ char.
As it, expressions as x''^2 raise a Double superscript error because the latex mechanism used to handle the prime symbol is defined with the standard catcode of the circumflex (7). I fixed that by redefining the latex \@pr@m@s macro with its original definition, but with the new catcode:
\begingroup \catcode`\^=12%
\gdef\@pr@m@s{% copy of \pr@m@s code from latex.ltx
  \ifx'\@let@token
  \expandafter\pr@@@s
\else
  \ifx^\@let@token
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\pr@@@t
  \else
    \egroup
  \fi
\fi}
\endgroup

I just found out that the package unicode-math has its own mechanism for the prime symbol. As I want to make my package compatible with unicode-math, I shall fix it.
The solution is to redefine the command \__um_superscript:n with its own definition and  the new catcode:
\ExplSyntaxOn
\group_begin:
\char_set_catcode_other:N \^
\cs_gset:Nn \__um_superscript:n % copy of \__um_superscript:n from unicode-math-luatex.sty
 {
  ^\bgroup #1
  \peek_meaning_remove:NTF ^ \__um_arg_i_before_egroup:n \egroup
 }
\group_end:
\ExplSyntaxOff

Question
Is there a better way to redefine properly the commands \@pr@m@s and \__um_superscript:n without having to copy/paste their definitions, so that they use the catcode 12 for the circumflex ^?
Example
This code raise errors:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\usepackage{altsubsup}

\begin{document}

circumflex catcode: \the\catcode`^

$ x^2 \quad x'^2 \quad x''^2 \quad x'''^{sup}$

\end{document}

This code don't raise errors, but I have to copy the definition of the command \__um_superscript:n:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\usepackage{altsubsup}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\group_begin:
\char_set_catcode_other:N \^
\cs_gset:Nn \__um_superscript:n
 {
  ^\bgroup #1
  \peek_meaning_remove:NTF ^ \__um_arg_i_before_egroup:n \egroup
 }
\group_end:
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

circumflex catcode: \the\catcode`^

$ x^2 \quad x'^2 \quad x''^2 \quad x'''^{sup}$

\end{document}


you could use \meaning and then \scantokens to re-parse it with new catcodes but that has other dangers.  Presumably you don't support ^^J etc whatever you do?

@DavidCarlisle Indeed, I don't support ^^J as the catcode of ^ is altered. I can copy/paste the existing definitions into my package, but if possible it would be better not to hardcode them. If there is no safe possibility, I'll go with copy/paste.

as I say you could try \scantokens\expandafter{\meaning but probably I'd copy the code rather than do that. It is what it is.

@DavidCarlisle Many thanks for your answer, I'll do that.

you should not redefine or use internal commands (those with two underscores like \__um_superscript:n) from unicode-math.

@UlrikeFischer I agree, but I see no other solution.

@UlrikeFischer I've maybe found something, but I'm not sure if it will always work. I posted another question here.
